# sql how to pick the top three values in each category

Tags: sql, row-number

I have a table contains  division, group, class, sub_class,
how to pick  the highest 3 counts in each sub_class

```
   select    division ,group,class,sub_class, count(*) as number_cnt, 

               ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by division ,group,class 
               order by  number_cnt ) as RowNum  
  from mydata 
  order by  division,group,class, number_cnt desc
```

then I want to pick the RowNum<=3
But it returns can not resolve number_cnt , but I need this number_cnt in order by.

mydata after I count the number of each sub_class will be like this

```
     division   group   class            subclass        number_cnt
     plant      fruit   tropical fruit   banana          10
                                         jackfruit       5
                                         passion fruit   3
                                         coconut         2
```

I hope to pick out  the top three counts for each division-group-class-subclass combination

```
     division   group   class            subclass        number_cnt
     plant      fruit   tropical fruit   banana          10
                                         jackfruit       5
                                         passion fruit   3
```

Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Whats the category here?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: it returns can not resolve number_cnt  error , but I think order by number_cnt is behind select.

Comment: I also feel confused about order by , inside the window function, the partition is set , do I need to order by division,group,class, number_cnt desc

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT division,
       group,
       class,
       sub_class,
       ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by trade_division ,group,class 
                       order by  number_cnt ) as RowNum   

  FROM
    (      select   division ,
                    group,
                    class,
                    sub_class, 
                    count(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY trade_division,group,class ) AS number_cnt               
           from my data 
     )

 WHERE RowNum <=3
order by  division,group,class, number_cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Assuming that you want the 10 highest subclasses for each division/group/class:

```
select t.*
from (select division, group, class, sub_class, count(*) as number_cnt, 
               row_number() over (partition by division, group, class
                                  order by count(*) desc
                                 ) as seqnum  
      from my data 
      group by division, group, class, sub_class
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

You want to use windows functions with aggregation.  Note that `sub_class` is in the `group by`, but not in the `partition by` for `row_number()`.

Note:  your column names are inconsistent.  And, you should **not** use SQL keywords (such as `group`) as column names.

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this helps.

```
    SELECT * from( 
    select    division ,group,class,sub_class, count(*) as number_cnt, 
    ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by trade_division ,group,class 
    order by  number_cnt ) as RowNum  
    from my data ) a
    WHERE RowNum<=3
```

Comment: Explaining your code and giving more detail would probably be helpful.